# Accessing Binding from Type Converter?

Tags: c#, wpf, typeconverter

I've spent a fair bit of time trying a number of different ways to solve an issue I'm having, to no avail, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

I have a Text Box element with Two-Way binding, which utilises a Type Converter to convert the value from a string to a custom Data type, say, `MyCustomType`. This is working fine, however due to a change in my project's requirements, I now need to perform extra processing prior to the conversion taking place.

In order to perform this extra processing, however, I need to be able to access the "source" text box, or the binding context. Neither of which I have been able to access.

Is there any way to access the source text box, from a Type Converter's `ConvertFrom()` method?

I have tried to use the `ITypeDescriptorContext` parameter passed (by WPF) to the `ConvertFrom()` method, however most of the properties therein are null.

i.e.

```
public class MyCustomTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
   ...
   public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
   {
      // Context is
      return new MyCustomType(value);
   }
   ...
}
```

[image: The context within ConvertFrom()]

[image: Context - additional properties]

I have also tried using a `MultiValueConverter`, and avoiding the Type converter entirely, however this led to a **LOT** of extra code, and didn't really help. I would prefer to avoid going down this route, as a Type Converter is much more elegant.

Any advice/assistance would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Why do you want to access binding? May be there is some other way around

Comment: I Don't think its possible to access Bindings from TypeConverters. They must be operating on DataLayer, also seems lot of unnecessary work. If you update the question what is the whole problem people may be able to help you that way much easily.

Comment: @Nitin, I was trying to access the source TextBox, so that I could pass it to another method (as a reference), so that I can perform specific tasks on validation failure.

This isn't necessarily the best way to do this, however the project's requirements have changed fairly late in the development stage, and this is a functional, somewhat-temporary solution.  (It's fairly high on my list of things to refactor when I get some time).

Thank you both for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I ended up changing the way that validation is performed (using `INotifyDataError` instead of validating on exceptions), and ended up re-writing the `ConvertFrom()` method in my Type Converter, such that I wouldn't need to access the `TypeDescriptor`'s context anymore.

I wouldn't recommend using the context from the ConvertFrom() method, as it (being a private property) isn't guaranteed that the property will exist in the future (though I haven't read anything to support this, it is best to assume that private properties can be removed/renamed without notification from the MS development team), and it isn't set when setting a property's value programmatically, like so:

```
TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(MyCustomType));
converter.ConvertFrom(mySourceValue);
```

If you're reading this and really need to access the `context` parameter, you can do so using my method below, at your own risk.

---

I was able to solve this by interrogating the [ValueConverterContext](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/MS/Internal/Data/DefaultValueConverter.cs,35f6e7a00ee8ccb6,references) class, and accessing the private `_targetElement` field, like this:

```
var sourceTextBox = context.GetType().GetField("_targetElement", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(context)
```

Thanks for your help nonetheless. :)

edit: To access the Bindings for this TextBox, you can simply cast `sourceTextBox` as `TextBox` and then:

```
var BindingExpression = sourceTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
```